# How do I use a JSON string as variable data for a Liquid.NET template?

Tags: c#, json, templates, liquid.net

I'm looking for the best way to use a JSON string as the variable data for a Liquid.NET template. I don't know the structure of the JSON so I am unable to deserialize it to a POCO before using it.

I attempted to use the .ToLiquid() extension method on a JSON.Net JObject but it throws a memory exception.

I may need to convert the JSON to a LiquidHash before merging it with the template. Is there a utility that provides this or do I need to iterate over all the nodes myself?

https://github.com/mikebridge/Liquid.NET

Comment: Perhaps @mikebridge could shed some light here? :)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there's no direct conversion from a JSON object to a LiquidHash.  It might be a useful feature to be able to import a JSON.Net datastructure but it's not there at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently need to generate a LiquidHash manually.